# Why is Vue js Method not working from click event?

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks, vue.js

I'm learning how to use Vue and one of the methods in my practice code isn't working, any idea why?

When clicking 'Add name' an alert should pop up, but it doesn't.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#array',
  data: {
    names: ['Jo', 'Joana', 'Joanna', 'Joan']
  },
   
methods: {
  addName: function() {
    alert('Adding name');
  }
}

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="array">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="name in names" v-text="name"> {{ names }} </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input type="text">
<button v-on:click="addName">Add name</button>
```

Comment: The button is not inside the Vue.

Comment: yeah, this is from the LaraCast and I had the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#array',
  data: {
    names: ['Jo', 'Joana', 'Joanna', 'Joan'],
    newName: ""
  },
  methods: {
    addName: function() {
      this.names.push(this.newName);
      this.newName = ""
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="array">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="name in names"> {{ name }} </li>
  </ul>
  <input v-model="newName" type="text">
  <button v-on:click="addName">Add name</button>
</div>
```